# Add custom template file to typo3 news extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I need to add own file in typo3 news extension. At this moment I try to add:

```
<numIndex index="482">
                                        <numIndex index="0">Custom</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">News->customList</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
```

In file: Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_news.xml And also I try to create files Custom.html in:

```
Resources/Private/Templates/News
Resources/Private/Templates/Styles/Twb/Templates/News
```

Unfortunately it not work. Typo3 still show error like that: Oops, an error occurred! Code: 20190918154251f8d68c46
Anyone know, what I doing wrong? I need only to add simple html file to custom "What to display" in typo3 admin.

Comment: *Never ever change an extension you imported.* You would not be able to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try to add further templates to the selection of layout of news for editors?

This can be done with [adding some page TSconfig](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/7.3/en-us/AdministratorManual/Configuration/TsConfig/Index.html#templatelayouts)